# Repeating code of for-loop for lines sharing same identifier value

Tags: python, csv

I have a textfile consisting of lines as follows:

```
12,538123,724026,8.01  
12,538123,724026,8.5  
12,538123,724026,8.91  
34,538123,724026,8.01  
34,538123,724026,8.5  
34,538123,724026,8.91
```

I have a script working that for-loops through the data, takes an element [-1] from each line and accumulates this to a new list.

What I can’t work out is how to do this for sets of lines sharing the same identifier (i.e. 12 in lines 1 and 2).

I tried an nested while-loop, but my problem is that my while condition is the identifier value itself (i.e., 12) so when I read in a new line with a different id (e.g. 34) this changes the condition for the while loop to the new id value. This (unsurprisingly) results in my accumulating a list of every [-1] value in one long list (my actual list has >200,000 lines). I tried an If statement within the For loop too and it does the same.

My problem is using the id as the condition, but I can't think of another way to do it.

Any ideas anyone?
Can it be done in a loop?
If I could summarise line sets that would possibly do it also (but I don’t know if this can be done).

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what exactly you're trying to do with your information. I think if you mocked up what the result of your while loop *should* be, that'd be helpful.

Comment: Please post your code and example outputs (wrong/current and desired). It'd be clearer that way.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean - can you provide what you want for your output given the input in your question? Also, could you provide the code you've tried (the "nested While loop" you mention)?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html) module? The [`DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) be useful by making your identifier a *key*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


d = {}
with open("some_file_name", "r") as f:
    lines = (line.split(",") for line in f)
    for k, g in groupby(lines, key=itemgetter(0)):
        d[k] = [line[-1] for line in g]
```

Add `float` etc. as needed. Result is in `d`.

Comment: Thanks WH. This looks like a nice elegant solution. I think I can use this. Thanks! Shaymo

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code:

```
results = {}
file = open("filename", "r")
for line in file.readlines():
    val_a, val_b, val_c, val_d = line.split(',')
    val_d = float(val_d)
    try:
        results[val_a] += val_d
    except KeyError:
        results[val_a] = val_d
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, This looks good (and easy for me to understand too). Very much appreciated. Shaymo